# HTMLAgilityPack - Remove Node with out stripping the inner text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

My html content is

```html
<a href="#asdf">asdf</a>
<H5 align="left"><A href="#d570525d497.htm#toc">Table 
of Contents</A><br></H5>
```

I'm using HTML Agility Pack to load the html. I want to find `<a>` nodes and remove the node without removing its inner text as mentioned below

```html
asdf
<H5 align="left">Table 
of Contents<br></H5>
```

I'm using below code,

```
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
var Nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
foreach (var Node in Nodes)
{
    Node.InnerText.Trim();
}
```

It's not working. Something wrong with the code?

Comment: I believe, it is the algorythm. You should get the inner html and place it to the parent.

Answer (score 10):

Remove the node from parent while keeping the grand children

```
foreach (var Node in Nodes)
{
    Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node, true); //<-- keepGrandChildren
}

var newhtml = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

output:

```
asdf
<h5 align="left">Table 
of Contents<br></h5>
```

Comment: Node does not have a parent node to use `Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node, true);`

Comment: @user2729272 at least all are in `<html>`. How about to try? (BTW: it works for your sample. I posted the output in the answer)

Comment: The example string you posted will be given a "parent" node of type Document...so from the perspective of Node.ParentNode it will work.